# eclipse creates extends ActionBarActivity instead activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

when I create a new android project Eclipse creates my MainActivity with extends ActionBarActivity instead activity. And want know how change this to when Eclipse creates my MainActivity extends activity.

thanks for you help!!!!

Comment: Mine is set to min. API 11 and I get the same error.
Worked before I update Eclipse Android

Answer (score 16):

**Note:** This answer is not valid anymore. At the time I answered this question, it was pre-material era and AppCompat library was necessary only if you want to target below API 11. Now to have Material Design, you almost have to use AppCompat library for all API levels. I think Android Studio always creates Activity that etends `AppCompatActivity` now.

And lastly do not use `ActionBarActivity`, use `AppCompatActivity`

---

If you set your minimum required SDK below 11 it will create the application like this because in API level below 11 there is no ActionBar. The default value is 8. You should set it 14 and then you can change it in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm learning android and there are much I don't know. One more time Thanks.